# Parameter "self" in logistic regression sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to run a logistic regression model from sklearn.

But when I run `model.fit()`, it asks 3 parameters `(self, X, and y)`. So what is this "self" parameter actually, and how can I run the model properly?

Here's my code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logR = LogisticRegression.fit(X = X_train, y= y_train)
```

and here's the error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-112-630096e6bf16> in <module>
      1 from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
----> 2 logR = LogisticRegression.fit(X = X_train, y= y_train)

TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Answer (score 3):

`Self` is not a parameter to input, it is an indicator for the OOP programming style.
In other words, ignore it.

```
logr = LogisticRegression()

logr.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

This should do the job.

[Click here to read more about Self](https://www.edureka.co/blog/self-in-python/#:%7E:text=The%20self%20is%20used%20to,attributes%20with%20the%20given%20arguments.&text=In%20Python%2C%20we%20have%20methods,automatically%2C%20but%20not%20received%20automatically.)